# multiprocessing error "AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'testfuncxx' on <module '__main__"

Tags: python, multiprocessing

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.5
import multiprocessing, time

def testfuncxx(num):
    time.sleep(num)
    print(num


pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=3)

)

for i in range(10):
    #testfuncxx(i)
    #print(i, '=======')
    pool.apply_async(testfuncxx, args=(i,))

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Comment: Are you running the code from IPython console or as a script file?

Comment: is your issue resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Since I can only test on Windows, the code works when I enclose the code in a `if __name__ == '__main__'` entry-point protection. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50781216/in-python-multiprocessing-process-do-we-have-to-use-name-main). In general, including this protection is recommended in the [multiprocessing guidelines](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#programming-guidelines).

**Note**: The code was run as a script *test.py*. To run the code in IPython or Jupyter notebook, you may import it like `import test`.

**test.py**:

```
import multiprocessing, time

def testfuncxx(num):
    time.sleep(num)    
    print(num)

def apply_async_callback():  
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=3) 
    for i in range(10):  
        pool.apply_async(testfuncxx, args=(i,))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()  


if __name__=='__main__':    
    apply_async_callback()

#Output:
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```